# Why would One table view in a tab view work fine while the other starts under the nav bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

I have an app I'm working on that uses a modified version of the master detail template. The app is document based so it stats with a table view that lists all the documents. Once a document is selected is slides in a tab bar that has three tabs, the first two of which are table views. Both table views have their own table view controller class that share a common custom superclass. The inheritance is `UITableViewController` -> `TMSTableViewController` -> `TMSExpensesTableViewController/TMSCategoriesTableViewController`. Whichever tab is first displays just as it should with the table starting below the navigation bar. The second tab to load however always starts at the top of the screen under the navigation bar so the first row and a half are hidden. If it was just one of the table views I would assume there was something wrong with the controller or view but I actually duplicated the scene for the first tab and even when they both had the same controller running them the second one still started at the top of the screen.

Have I found a bug in iOS7 or is there some strange trick that I need to do when using multiple table views in a tab bar?

The tables each display a single Core Data entity type and `TMSTableViewController` has all of the common code for dealing with the fetched results controller and most of the table view code as well. The only methods in the two subclasses are to configure the cell as appropriate based on which kind of entity is being displayed, set the fetched results controller to have to proper entity, and add the proper kind of entity when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the result of a bug in iOS 7. The workaround is to use the following code in all but the first table view:

```
CGRect barFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake((barFrame.origin.y + barFrame.size.height), 0, tabFrame.size.height, 0);
```

I use this code wrapped in an `#ifdef` so that when it gets fixed I can easily remove the associated `#define` and have all the code fall away.